# MATLAB CSV Import Warping Data

Tags: matlab, csv, import, stock

When I import my data (numerical matrix of NYSE stock data), the data isn't loaded properly:

the final part of my CSV data disp() displayed should be -

9.76, 10, 9.99, 9.94, 9.97,9.944,9.95,10,9.956,10.01

What I get when I call the disp(importDataResult) is -

0.0100 0.0099 0.0099 0.0100 etc..

Have you got any idea why when I import the data it is transformed completely? The below link contains my zipped CSV file so you can see the problem (I completely understand if you can't be bothered checking this out, but I'd be interested to know if the same problem applies to others' MATLAB / computers).

https://www.sendspace.com/file/slif0y

The code I'm using is:

```
function [ c ] = CreateCov_Test()
c = csvread('nyse_data_matrix_no_tags.csv');
disp(c);
end
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
https://s32.postimg.org/os74qfrlx/matlab_screen.png

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's probably better to do a `csvread` if your data are all numeric and `textscan` if it contains strings

Comment: Hi, when I do CSVread the same problem remains - is the numerical matrix too big for MATLAB to handle? I've tried using the 'import data' button, the importdata() function and now the csvread() function. All of them transform the data when I import it - the code is so simple I don't get what can be going wrong.

Thanks for trying though! :)

Comment: Make sure there's not a `1.00e+03` or something like that out front of your displayed text result.  This is just Matlab making things fit in the `format short` output.

Comment: Hi Matt, that's strange that it would do that considering the values it is trying to import are things generally between 0 and 100 (not integers). Following is some sample output: ---

   0.0137    0.0135    0.0100
    0.0137    0.0134    0.0099
    0.0137    0.0135    0.0099
    0.0137    0.0138    0.0100
    0.0137    0.0136    0.0100
    0.0138    0.0136    0.0100

--- there is no e or + that I can see, could this still be the problem? I've been trying to work this one out for weeks so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to plot your data! It is *not* between 0-100! `plot(c)`

Comment: or just check your data using `min(importDataResult)` and  `max(importDataResult)`.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam in this case, this might be better `min(importDataResult(:))`and `max(importDataResult(:))` otherwise you'll get min-value for each column.

Comment: Hi Jorgen, I realise the whole of my data isn't between 0 and 100, but as it is stock value data, most of it is within this range (no stocks are worth less than 0 and not many are worth more than 100). I was making the point to show that I'd be surprised if the size of the values was forcing MATLAB to transform it to 'format short'. Interestingly when I type plot(data) the data hasn't been transformed, it is simply when I type disp(data) that it becomes extremely small. I am wondering do you also have this problem? Thanks a lot for the help and consideration guys!

Comment: I'll attach a screenshot of the problem: https://s32.postimg.org/os74qfrlx/matlab_screen.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab is not transforming any data. The configuration of who Matlab is displaying variables is controlled with [format](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html), the default being `format short`.

An excerpt from the documentation:

> format may be used to switch between different output display formats of all float variables as follows:
>
> format SHORT     Scaled fixed point format with 5 digits.

So what does *Scaled fixed point format with 5 digits* mean, well lets see

```
>> a = [0.1 10000 100]
>> disp(a)
   1.0e+04 *

    0.0000    1.0000    0.1000
```

Note the `1.0e+04 *`, its a multiplier for all data in the matrix. When displaying a large matrix, this multiplier is often hidden (as in your case), which admittedly can be rather confusing.

Comment: Hi Jorgen, thanks for your answer! I now understand what you meant, the multiplier is hidden as the output is larger than the output space. So if I were to export the result to CSV, the numbers would be back to normal? Unfortunately my free trial of MATLAB ran out today so I'll have to wait until I get to university to get this CSV (which is annoying as I need to write a java investment algorithm with the result)... either way thank you for your time!